# Any value that makes a JavaScript comparison always true?

Tags: javascript, comparison, operators

Is there any JavaScript value that makes a comparison always true?

**Example with lower than operator:**

```
true < 10           true
false < 10          true
null < 10           true
```

**Example with greater than operator:**

```
true > 10           false
false > 10          false
null > 10           false
```

**What I'm looking for:**

```
alwaysTrue < 10     true
alwaysTrue > 10     true
```

I want to use this to make one part of an if statement return true by default and true or false when the first comparison value is changed.

This is probably not existent but I want to be completely sure.

Comment: It seems to me possible only with operator overloading and the first argument being an object. operator overloading is none existent in JS. Would you accept something like Arg1.comparison(Arg2) instead of generic operators?

Comment: If there was a comparison operator that *always* returned true, wouldn't that be a bug? Since it would, in effect, not be comparing anything?

Comment: @Itay Moav Don't know exactly how that would look like but I welcome your code so I can try it.

Comment: @David Thomas Not completely. You could store that special always true value in a variable and then change the variable when you don't want it to be always true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to consider leveraging "or" in your condition with another variable that can trump whether it returns true or not.

```
returnTrue || testVariable < 10
```

This will always return true when returnTrue is set to true, otherwise it will fall back on the comparison.  If you are just looking for a change in a variable you can do so by storing the old value.  If you know it will never be null you can check on this, otherwise you can use the the "or" with a flag similar to above.

```
oldValue === null || currentValue === oldValue
```

Comment: This one comes close. You need to add an extra variable but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are asking, but this is a way of doing it with a few more statements:

```
var rtn = true;

if (oldCompareValue != newCompareValue) {
   // next you'll want to insert your return expression
   // i'm not sure you've specified what this should be
   rtn = (newCompareValue > 10)? true: false;
}

return rtn;
```

You can also do this using the AND operator as you've requested:

```
rtn = true;

if ((oldCompareValue != newCompareValue) && true) {
   rtn = (newCompareValue > 10)? true: false;
}

return rtn;
```

The if statement does the following for us:

1. if oldCompareValue is the same as newCompareValue then the whole statement is false
2. if oldCompareValue is not the same as newCompareValue then the whole statement is true

In either case the right part of the test expression always evaluates to true, and you'll only enter the if when the left part passes as well. However, keeping that true in place seems excessive to me.

Once you got you're logic in place this can go into one line.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not find any. Having such an object would be very helpful when comparing missing dates for instance.

There are however values that are always `false`:

```
NaN > 10 // false
NaN < 10 // false
undefined < 10 // false
undefined > 10 // false
```

Hence their negation will be always `true`:

```
!(NaN > 10) // true
!(NaN < 10) // true
!(undefined < 10) // true
!(undefined > 10) // true
```

You can hence rewrite your statement using the negation:

```
value > 10

!(value < 10)
```